# gnu makefile strange problem

Tags: makefile

here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = 

all: tm

tm: tm.exe

tm.exe: tm.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -otm tm.c
```

and i got this result:

```
gcc  -otm tm.c
gcc     tm.c tm.exe   -o tm
tm.exe: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tm] Error 1
```

why "tm.exe" in "gcc tm.c tm.exe -o tm" comes out????

if i change my makefile into this one:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = 

all: tm.exe

tm.exe: tm.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -otm tm.c
```

it works well...

thanks previously...

i use gnu make version 3.81 in win7 platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add a rule for making `tm` from `tm.exe`. However, you don't actually need to specify the `.exe` extension on Windows, this will be handled automatically. So just say it like this:

```
.phony: all clean

all: tm

tm: tm.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $+ $(LDFLAGS)

tm.o: tm.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: sorry, the makefile is too long. so i fail to add it to the comment. anyway, thanks very much. your reply helps a lot...